# How do I edit this code so the navbar items are left, centred and right aligned?

Tags: html, css

I need help in editing my code to justify the navbar items to be left aligned, centered and right aligned as well as responsive. The code I've attempted moves my dropdown buttons to outside the navbar or removes the CSS.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #c2d6d6;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #009999;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #85adad;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Internal Auditor Training</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ISO 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">9001</a>
      <a href="#">17025</a>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Verification 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Balance</a>
      <a href="#">Gravimetric POVA 2</a>
      <a href="#">Thermometer/ Data logger</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can add `text-align` property to `dropdown` class.

Comment: I had to cut down my code to be allowed to post my question so the code snippet won't work...

Comment: draw a diagram (picture) "as a result it should be" and attach it here

Answer (score 0):

*From your question, this is what I understand. You have a navbar and wants to align its elements, one to the left, one centred and one right aligned.*

**If so, you can use a CSS flex-box to align them. Make a flex container and set the justify-content property to space-between. `justify-content: space-between;`**

Refer the code snippet below ⇓

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

#a,
#b,
#c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:15px;
}

#a {
  background: red;
}

#b {
  background: orange;
}

#c {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="a">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    2
  </div>
  <div id="c">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```